# Use facebook app Id on multiple domains

Tags: javascript, facebook

I had registered a facebook app for my website. And my problem is that I use **single sign on** for my website.

User must login with their facebook account in **www.site1.com**, then they will be redirected to **www.site2.com**.

How can i use the same register app Id on 2 sites for future functions. I want to use facebook javascript sdk to some stuff on **www.site2.com**

Thanks for your help. Nice day !

Answer (score 1):

single sign-on:

SSO is simply logging a user with facebook and maintaining a site-wide session on your server and cookie on user's machine. This session shall remain valid for all pages on your website.

1) http://blog.mixu.net/2010/12/27/implementing-facebook-login-single-sign-on-part-1/

2) http://blog.mixu.net/2011/01/03/implementing-facebook-login-part-2/

3) http://blog.mixu.net/2011/01/09/implementing-facebook-login-part-3/